# I have machine learning data with binary features. How can I force an autoencoder to return binary data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, binary, autoencoder

I have a dataset of the following form: A series of M observations of N-dimensional data. In order to obtain latent factors from this data, I wish to make a single hidden-layer autoencoder trained on this data. Every dimension of a single observation is either a 0 or a 1. But the keras Model returns floats. Is there a way to add a layer to enforce a 0 or 1 as output?

I tried using a simple keras Model to solve this problem. It claims good accuracy on the data, but when looking at the raw data it predicts the 0's correctly and often completely ignores the 1's.

```py
n_nodes = 50
input_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu')(input_1)
output_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(x_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_1, output_1)
my_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
my_optimizer.lr = 0.002
model.compile(optimizer=my_optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10000)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

These observations I then validate by looking at all experiments and seeing if a large (>0.1) value is returned for the elements which are 1. The performance is very poor on the 1's.

I have seen that the loss converges around 10000 epochs. However, the autoencoder fails to properly predict almost all 1's in the data set. Even when setting the width of the hidden layer to be identical to the dimensionality of the data (`n_nodes = x_train.shape[1]`) the autoencoder still gives bad performance, even worsening if I increase the width of the hidden layer.

Answer (score 2):

`[0, 1]` outputs should generally be rounded such that >=0.5 rounds to 1 when outputting a final prediction and <0.5 rounds to 0. However your labels should be float values `{0.0, 1.0}` for the loss function (which I expect they are already). You can compute accuracy by rounding the outputs and comparing to your binary labels to count errors for `{0, 1}`, but they must be in continuous form `[0.0, 1.0]` for the loss and gradient calculations to work.

If you are doing all of that (and it does appear that things are set up correctly in your code), there might be a number of reasons for poor performance:

1. Your dense, "constriction" layer should be significantly smaller than your input. In making it smaller you are forcing the auto-encoder to learn a representative form of the input that can be used to produce the output. This representative form is likely to generalize well. If you increase the size of your hidden layer the network will have much more capacity to memorize the inputs.
2. You might have many more `0` values than `1` values, if this is the case then in the absence of actual learning the network could get stuck just predicting 0 as a "best guess" because that's "usually right". This is a harder problem to tackle. You might consider multiplying the loss by a vector of `labels * eta + 1`, this would effectively increase the learning rate of the ones labels. Example: Your labels are `[0, 1, 0]`, eta is a hyper-parameter value >1, let's say eta=2.0. `labels * eta = [1.0, 3.0, 1.0]` which scales up the gradient signal for 1 values by increasing the loss for only `1`'s. This isn't a bullet proof method of increasing the importance of the `1`'s class, but it's something simple to try. If it makes any improvement then follow up on this line of reasoning in more detail.
3. You have 1 hidden layer, which means your limited to linear relationships, you might try 3 hidden layers to add a little non linearity. Your center layer should be fairly small, try something like 5 or 10 neurons, it should need to squeeze the data into a fairly tight constriction point to extract a general purpose representation.

Comment: Case 2) was the major issue. There was a 10-to-1 class imbalance between zeroes and ones. I am now working on a custom loss as you suggested. Thanks very much for the help!